# Getting error while saving through Filestorage using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

I am trying to save the vocabulary from the BOW algorithm.  Below is my code.

```
FileStorage fs; 
fs.open("Vocabulary.xml", FileStorage::WRITE); 
Mat vocabulary = bow.cluster(); 
fs << vocabulary ;
fs.release();
FileStorage fs2; 
fs2.open("Vocabulary.xml", FileStorage::READ); 
fs2 ["Vocabulary"] >> vocabulary ;
dextract.setVocabulary(vocabulary);

cv::Mat training_mat(num_img , dictionarySize,CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat labels(num_img,1,CV_32FC1);

CvSVM svm;
svm.load( "trainsvm.xml" );
```

Here is my error :

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (No element name has been given) in unknown function , file c:\opencv\2.4.4\build\include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp , line 2908
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't setting the name of your vocabulary in the file, try this:

```
fs << "Vocabulary" << vocabulary ;
```